# what happens if browser doesn't support X-FRAME-OPTIONS

Tags: authentication, iframe

What happens if browser doesn't support X-FRAME-OPTIONS?

Does it render the uri referenced by the iframe OR it doesn't render anything in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A browser that supports frames but not the `X-Frame-Options` header (or the corresponding CSP policies) will simply render any frame content, regardless of the origin. It can't implement a security mechanism that it doesn't know about.

`X-Frame-Options` was implemented by most major browser around 2010 (and only later specified in [RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) in year 2013) - at that time, frames have already long been around. Introducing the header was a reaction to the [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) problem that arised due to  cross-origin frame embedding which couldn't be fully remediated with [framebusting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) techniques.

Comment: Thx Aminius, can you please back your answer by a reference? Then I will accept the answer.

Comment: He is right. Why dont you just test it? People dont write documentation in their browsers for nonexistant features.

Comment: @zatziky I'm not sure about what references you're looking for. `X-Frame-Options` came after the frame technology, so obviously a browser that doesn't know about the header would just ignore it.

Comment: @Arminius Thx, it helps me to understand when I read it in other words and other thoughts.

Comment: @zatziky The linked RFC has a little bit of historical background if you're interested.

Comment: @Arminius I have a look!

Comment: @Arminius, you've got a lot of points in Security stack exchange. Would you mind to have a look at another question of mine? :) It is the question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153577/secure-a-page-in-iframe-from-being-used-outside .